# How do you reopen minecraft.exe on Windows 10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have downloaded minecraft.exe, and it opened as soon as it was done downloading,  my problem is, I see no way to open it again if I close out of it. (Also, my Operating System is Windows 10). I also cannot find it in my downloads folder, or anywhere it is like I never even had it. And, I did not delete it.

Yay! I fixed it! Come to find out I am an idiot, I did not click save while downloading! I just deleted the .exe and installed the regular one. (I tried the regular before but it did not work, so I thought I needed the .exe) Thanks for the suggestions! :)

Comment: You downloaded it from the [official site,](http://minecraft.net) right?

Comment: If you figured out an answer to your own question, feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you have opened it before, you can use Windows' 10 new function called 'Quick Access' which helps you find 20 of your most recently opened files. You could right click on your file and click on 'Open folder location' to find your download

By default all your downloads are in the downloads folder

If you used Chrome to download, press CTR+J and find your download. Then click on open folder location.

If you used Firefox to download, press CTR+J and there would be a little folder button floating around. Click it to see where you downloaded it

Answer (score 1):

Go to the place where your download was saved, usually this is: ***C:\Users\YourpcUsername\documents\downloads***, from where you can either run the .exe file again or you can drag it onto your Desktop by holding the left mouse button on it so you don't have to go into the folder every time.

If this isn't your problem please give more detail on the problem.